# Cloudera SCM Agent can't heartbeat but port is contactable

Tags: networking, big-data, cloudera, cloudera-manager

I'm trying to add nodes to a Cloudera cluster. When the agent starts I get a python stacktrace saying it can't heartbeat to master-host:7182, however I can connect to that port just fine.

The stacktrace is from Python and ends saying the connection timed out.

`nc -z 1 -w master-host 7182` returns "connection successful"

Firewalls are off, SELinux is in Permissive.

Each box has 2 IPs, one in the 4 space and one in the 8 space. The DNS resolves the 8 address and the hosts file resolves the 4 address.

EDIT: To add some more info, based on [this post](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Cloudera-Manager-Installation/Warning-in-CM-The-host-s-Cloudera-Manager-Agent-s-software/td-p/27346):

- OS Versions are the same, agent/manager versions are the same
- I can connect from the CM host to the 4 address, port 9000. The 4 address is the one that shows up in the Host page on Cloudera Manager
- The large ping command fails on the 4 address: `ping -c 3 -s 1800 4-address`, MTU for this interface is set to 9000.
- The large ping command passes on the 8 address, MTU is set to 1500.

Comment: I fixed it with synchronization of clocks. Here's a step by step guide to do it: [http://www.yourtechchick.com/hadoop/failed-receive-heartbeat-agent-cloudera-hadoop/](http://www.yourtechchick.com/hadoop/failed-receive-heartbeat-agent-cloudera-hadoop/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the MTU appeared to be the issue - the infrastructure we're using wasn't supporting jumbo frames end-to-end (in this case, Cisco c240m4s with fibre interconnects needed the QoS settings updating via UCS).